# Is there an easy way to manage a large number of conditional formatting rules?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Using Excel 2010, I've created a very large number of conditional formatting rules. You can see how small the thumb is - there are a *lot* of them.

[image]

Unfortunately, the conditional rules manager dialog box is *not* resizable, so I can't see more than a few characters of the formula, and in many cases, I can't see all the cells that a rule applies to. I have two very similar worksheets in my workbook which need a *nearly* identical set of rules (same rules, just different columns in the formulas).

Are there any tools available, as add-ons, plug-ins, or otherwise, to allow for the easier managing of a large number of conditional formatting rules?

I'm at the point of manually copying each rule (rule, format, applies to & stop) to a different spreadsheet, then manually recreating each rule, in order, in the other worksheet, and this just sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: What kind of management do you want to do? If you want to copy all formats from one sheet to another or just export them for review, VBA can handle that.

Comment: @EngineerToast - I need to be able to review the rules to ensure that I've got all situations covered, then, when the rule set is good, copy the rules to another worksheet within the workbook. After I posted, I started thinking along the lines of using VBA. I'm thinking I'll use VBA to export to either a standalone workbook, or a new worksheet within the existing workbook, do my editing and management there, then more code to load the formatting back in.

Comment: Great! If you get stuck somewhere on that, come back and update the question to show what you have and in what way it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your "nightmare" scenario could actually be used as part of a solution.  Don't copy the formulas from a different workbook, instead  use a new sheet in the current work book and test the value against the formulas on that sheet.

Now maintenance is as simple adjusting the formula on that sheet.

Tip: hide the sheet to protect it from user edits.

Pro tip: create a named range for each condition and use the VBA editor to make the sheet "Very Hidden".  Anyone fumbling through the name editor or format rules will be amazed at how you magically conjure colors from names, that is,  unless your users are saavy enough to peek behind the curtain by changing the sheet properties in the VBA editor or unpacking the XLSX to edit the XML.