# Excel 2013 & VBA > Count number of conditional formatting rules on sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Excel has a limit of the number of conditional formatting rules a sheet can handle before it locks up and prevents any more from being added. This can become an issue in complex sheets where one or more users or VBA scripts does a lot of copying and pasting and unintentionally duplicate rules.

When you use 'Manage Rule..." in Excel, it gives you a tiny box showing the list of all rules present on the sheet (assuming you select 'This Worksheet' as your scope). But this doesn't help me determine whether a sheet has fifty rules or a thousand rules, and doesn't help quantify the risk associated with that sheet's current condition.

Therefore: **How can I determine the number of Conditional Formatting Rules present on an Excel spreadsheet?**

---

Related: *[Is there an easy way to manage a large number of conditional formatting rules?](https://superuser.com/q/1086445/453948)*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how comfortable you are with VBA, but here's a simple script that will find the answer for an active worksheet and display it in a message box:

```
Sub CountConditions()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count & " Conditional Formatting rule(s) found on the current worksheet."
End Sub
```

Open the Visual Basic Editor, either from the **Developer** tab or with **Alt+F11**, right-click on your file's name on the left and choose Insert | Module, then you can copy the code above into the module to create a macro that will do the job for you.

With more complex code you can add conditions to look at each rule and maybe delete duplicates, etc.

Comment: Werff I'm not sure your answer is what he needed. I don't believe there's a limit on the "number of defined rules" on a range (although it was 3 up through XL03), though people have reported blowing out at 5000 or such. FormatConditions.Count reports 0,1,2 or 3(or higher for XL07+) but it doesn't report 9000 if you copy A1 to A2:A3000 when there are 3 format conditions in A1(what he did). .Count==3 for that range. (Also note,it is -1 if a range contains a different .Count for each cell). He MIGHT want to count the ROWS with cells with .Count<>0 as there was (still is?) a limit there of 2050.

Comment: IOW, .FormatConditions.Count returns the "number of rules that are used" by a range, not the number of "uses of rules" by a range. That is, in my example above, it reports 3, not 9000. Since O.P. said he copied a lot of cells, .FormatConditions.Count would not give an indication of the large number of USES of conditional format. It would give the same "small" number whether he copied a cell 10 times or 10,000.